# how to declare a function result types outside of a function in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two forms of the same function in postgres (see below) they both return a "table" result set of the same type. The way they are defined is not DRY (don't repeat yourself), is there a way to declare the result set only once ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation_report(_accession text)
  RETURNS TABLE (
      accession VARCHAR,
      peptide VARCHAR,
      modified_sequence VARCHAR,
      var_mod text,
      spectrum_title VARCHAR,
      confidence real,
      precursor_mz_error real,
      sample_name  text,
      transcript  text,
      gene_symbol  VARCHAR,
      prot_seq  text
  ) AS
$func$
BEGIN

   RETURN query select * from validation_report(array[_accession]);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation_report(_accession text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (
      accession VARCHAR,
      peptide VARCHAR,
      modified_sequence VARCHAR,
      var_mod text,
      spectrum_title VARCHAR,
      confidence real,
      precursor_mz_error real,
      sample_name  text,
      transcript  text,
      gene_symbol  VARCHAR,
      prot_seq  text
  ) AS
$func$
BEGIN

   RETURN QUERY ..the query..

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to return a Composite Type or use a `RETURN SETOF table_name` if function makes a query on a particular table. If not you can create a table/type to define the return type.

See example of `SETOF` here: http://nixmash.com/postgresql/returning-tables-from-postgresql-functions-in-sql-and-plpgsql/